# Soql does not return record Id in main class. But returns in Test class

Tags: apex, rest, apexrest

Hope you all are doing well.

I have a issue when writing test class. I have created a method where I am inserting a objectA record. Once the ObjectA record is inserted, objectB record get automatically created. So I am just querying it and assigning it to Id variable in Main class. This works fine.

But when I run the test class, ObjectA record gets created. But the query does not return ObjectB record Id.

Below is the code of Main class.

```
public static string createfeeditem(){
    Id docid;

    // Some lines omitted

    insert ObjectArecord;

    // Here it returns nothing when I run the Test class. 
    docid=[select field1,field2 from objectB where field2=:objectArecord.id].id; 
    return docid;
}
```

In Test class, I have created both the record ObjectA record and ObjectB record and also written the query. Also in Test class query, the ObjectB record Id is returned. But in main class the query returns nothing. so return statement does not get the record Id

Please assist what is going wrong here. I get **Invalid id:** error when test class is run.

Comment: Did you try to use the "System.runA" method? and using a user, who has access to this Object "ObjectB"?
Since Admin has access to everything, give your user a SysAdmin Profile, just to see if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Try using SaveResultClass, once you insert/update the record you might be able to get these values and check the Id itself. More info: [SaveResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) 
Otherwise, create a method using @setup annotation before running the test methods, and query the items.

Comment: How many entries do you expect after insert ObjectArecord? If you only expect 1. Can you please execute the following after insert:

System.debug('size: ' + [select field1,field2 from objectB].size());

Comment: I think that most likely field2 is of type string which is storing the reduced form of the id that is why your query is not returning a result.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for all your reply. I added method code in try catch block and it resolved the issue. The return statement got the record id.